# Iteration over list of strings in Python

Tags: python

Let us have a list of strings: `fruit = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]`. I would like to have an output that prints out all the possible pairs, i.e.

```
apple - apple, apple - orange, apple - banana, 
orange - orange, orange - banana, 
banana - banana
```

My idea was to `enumerate` fruit and do the following:

```
for icnt, i in fruit:
    jcnt = icnt
    j = i
    print ("icnt: %d, i: %s", icnt, i)
    for jcnt, j in fruit:
        print ("i: %s, j: %s", i, j)
```

Expectantly the string does not start from the `icnt-th` position but from the start. How to make the second loop to start from the i-th string?

Comment: use `itertools.combinations`

Comment: As @Jean-FrançoisFabre says, you should use `itertools.combinations` but to answer your question, you have to slice the `fruit` list in the second loop like so: `for jcnt, j in enumerate(fruit[icnt:]):` Also if you are going to use `enumerate`, do so.

Answer (score 3):

use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` to do this:

```
import itertools

for a,b in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(["apple", "orange", "banana"],2):
    print("{} - {}".format(a,b))
```

output:

```
apple - apple
apple - orange
apple - banana
orange - orange
orange - banana
banana - banana
```

or `itertools.combinations` if you don't want any repeats:

```
apple - orange
apple - banana
orange - banana
```

BTW your fixed code would look like this with `enumerate`:

```
fruit = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]

for icnt, i in enumerate(fruit):
     for jcnt in range(icnt,len(fruit)):
        print ("{} - {}".format(i, fruit[jcnt]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Use `itertools`:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

fruit = ["apple", "orange", "banana"]

print('\n'.join((' - '.join(perm) for perm in combinations_with_replacement(fruit, 2))))
# apple - apple
# apple - orange
# apple - banana
# orange - orange
# orange - banana
# banana - banana
```

Comment: This isn't exactly what is shown in the OP e.g you don't have apple-apple

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thanks. got that fixed